Create a spark connection to a Remote SQL Server instance
This is the first time I have had to set up a connection this complex, and the first time I have done it with Spark. I need to be able to connect to my company's remote Windows server that runs SQL Server. I need to use Spark in order to pull data from that server and eventually land it in an S3 bucket. I have attempted to use the below Scala code in spark shell.
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=<hostname>;port=1433 ;databaseName=<database name>")
  .option("dbtable", "olap.vDimOffice")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()

when I try to run this I get the following error
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$2(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:221)

I have looked for and downloaded what I thought was the correct driver: sqljdbc_12.6.1.0_enu.tar.  but the error remains. The primary question I have, is what all do I need to have in order to make this connection work and pull data from this server? Or, do I need to rethink my approach altogether?

Unzip that downloaded file and copy it to jar folder present in spark folder.
